# vb2008 retrieve value from combobox selected item and display to multiple textboxes

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox

I wanted to ask how to get combobox's selected value then display it to multiple textboxes. The combobox is populated with illnesses from the database. Now when an illness is selected from combobox, the symptoms of that illness should be displayed in many textboxes. Currently I have 10 textboxes for the symptoms. The table structure is id, illness, symptoms. Here's my code:

```
Dim mycmd As New MySqlCommand
Dim dtr As MySqlDataReader
Call Connect()
        Dim str As String
        str = "Select symptoms from diagnose where illness = @ill"
        mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ill", cmbRecord.Text)
        mycmd.CommandText = str
        dtr = mycmd.ExecuteReader
        While dtr.Read()
            symp0.Text = dtr("symptoms")
            symp1.Text = dtr("symptoms")
            symp2.Text = dtr("symptoms")
            symp3.Text = dtr("symptoms")
            symp4.Text = dtr("symptoms")
            symp5.Text = dtr("symptoms")
            symp6.Text = dtr("symptoms")
            symp7.Text = dtr("symptoms")
            symp8.Text = dtr("symptoms")
            symp9.Text = dtr("symptoms")
        End While
myConn.Close()
```

when an illness is selected from the combobox the symptoms should display on those textboxes. Say the selected illness has only 4 symptoms in the table, then `symp0` to `symp3` textbox will show the symptoms one by one and leaving the remaining textboxes blank.

The problem is that when an illness is selected, those textboxes displays only the last symptom of that illness stored in the database.

Example: fever. In the table, it has 4 symptoms: cold, hot temperature, headache, dizziness. If fever is selected, only dizziness is displayed from `symp0` to `symp9` textboxes.

Comment: You seriously need to reconsider your design, if you have to write code like this many times: `sympX.Text`, where `X=0:1:9` (0 through 9).

Comment: @Neolisk - I'm sorry sir, I'm just a newbie and still learning..I can't figure out what do you mean. How will I use that "`sympX.Text`, where `X=0:1:9` (0 through 9)"?..did you mean I should replace those `symp0.Text` through `symp9.Text` with `sympX.Text` and declare a x as integer, then write `x=0:1:9` ?

Comment: It means you should at least have an array of Textboxes, with 10 elements, before you even go for working with databases. You would then have a loop to iterate through all of them, and only one assignment operation. Your code becomes clean and easy to read/maintain. Also read my answer - was too big for a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dtr("symptoms")` gets a value of column `"symptoms"` from the current row. Between assignment to Textboxes #1 through #10 you do not advance reader to the next row, this is why you are seeing the same value in all textboxes.

Now to answer your question why it's **the last symptom** in all textboxes. By looping through rows with `dtr.Read()`, you re-assign values of Textboxes every time, and it happens until the last one is assigned. At which point no subsequent assignments are made, so the last value remains on the screen.

What you are looking for is probably something like this:

```
Dim symptoms As New List(Of String)
While dtr.Read()
  symptoms.Add(dtr("symptoms"))     
End While

'set available symptoms
Dim arrayOfTextboxes() As TextBox = {symp0, ... put all textboxes here..., symp9}
Dim i As Integer = 0
For i = 0 To symptoms.Count - 1
  arrayOfTextboxes(i).Text = symptoms(i)
Next

'clear other textboxes
For j = i to UBound(arrayOfTextboxes)
  arrayOfTextboxes(j).Text = String.Empty
Next
```

This is assuming you have less than 10 symptoms to display. For any number of symptoms, you could have used a `ListBox` by setting its `DataSource` to `symptoms`. Your code becomes more compact:

```
Dim symptoms As New List(Of String)
While dtr.Read()
  symptoms.Add(dtr("symptoms"))     
End While
YourListBoxWithSymptoms.DataSource = symptoms
```

Comment: yay!! it works now sir :D I used textboxes because the form is for updating or inserting a record in the database. A million thanks to you sir. God speed :)

Comment: @VBeginner: You could have used a ListBox for updating and inserting records, if you also had Add/Remove buttons. As a side note, if the answer was helpful, you can also upvote it.

Comment: @Neolisk: I wasn't able to upvote your answer yesterday because my reputation was under 15 the last time I was online hehe, anyway thanks for reminding me sir :)

Comment: anyway, if you don't mind sir, could I ask 1 more question regarding my post above?..or should I make a new post?, I just wanted to ask how can I update it? I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @VBeginner: Generally, after accepting the answer, it's best to create a new question. Otherwise if you change the meaning of the question, and the answer becomes non-applicable, it may look odd. Though you can reference this question in your other question. Do that if it helps you explain the problem. Editing your question is as easy as clicking *edit* under the tags.

Comment: @Neolisk: I already posted another question sir. The answer to that question has something to do with your answer above. I think I should apply it there, then I tried but failed to make it work. This is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912146/vb2008-how-to-insert-and-update-database-table-rows-using-textboxes#comment20919878_14912146
Please, forgive me sir for bothering you. I'm just desperate to finish this asap because this is my project for our finals :'(