# VB 2008 how to insert and update database table rows using textboxes

Tags: mysql, vb.net, textbox

I'm doing a part of my system which is updating and/or inserting data into database. I have a form with a combobox and 10 textboxes. Here, the combobox if filled with illnesses from the diagnose table in my database.

Diagnose table's structure is: f_id, illness, symptoms, so an illness can have many symptoms.

If an item is selected from the combobox, the symptoms will be displayed on the textboxes. I already got this working. My problem is that I should make it able to insert  or update the rows in the table. I really don't have any idea how to do this. So far, here's my code:

```
Call Connect()
        If Duplicate() = False Then

            STRSQL = "insert into diagnose values ('', @ill, @sym0), ('', @ill, @sym1), ('', @ill, @sym2), ('', @ill, @sym3), ('', @ill, @sym4), ('', @ill, @sym5), ('', @ill, @sym6), ('', @ill, @sym7), ('', @ill, @sym8), ('', @ill, @sym9)"
            Using myCmd = New MySqlCommand(STRSQL, myConn)
                myConn.Open()
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ill", cmbRecord.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym0", symp0.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym1", symp1.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym2", symp2.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym3", symp3.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym4", symp4.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym5", symp5.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym6", symp6.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym7", symp7.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym8", symp8.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym9", symp9.Text)
                myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
            MsgBox("Record Added")
            myConn.Close()
        Else
            STRSQL = "Update diagnose set first_aid = @ill, sname = @symp where first_aid = @ill"
            Using myCmd = New MySqlCommand(STRSQL, myConn)
                myConn.Open()
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ill", cmbRecord.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym", symp0.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym", symp1.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym", symp2.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym", symp3.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym", symp4.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym", symp5.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym", symp6.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym", symp7.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym", symp8.Text)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sym", symp9.Text)
                myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
            MsgBox("Record Updated")
            myConn.Close()
        End If
```

I already have a module that connect my project to mysql db (myConn). What I can't do is that I can't update any row in the diagnose table. I also can't add rows. The diagnose table look like this(example):

```
f_id | illness |  symptom
1   |  fever   |  fever
2   |  fever   |  hot temperature
3   |  fever   |  dizziness
4   |  fever   |  headache
```

so in that case, say I chose fever in the combobox then it will display the symptoms on the 4 textboxes. If the user made changes, the `Duplicate()` function checks if the combobox value already have a record. If true then it will update. Say the user added another symptom, so if save button is clicked, fever will add another row with the added symptom.

If false, then a new record will be added, which means new row or rows will be added in the table dependeng on the number of symptoms inputted on the textboxes. So, say 'cold' is to be added as a new record and I entered 2 symptoms, this means that I used 2 of the 10 textboxes in the form, then 2 rows will be added on the table.

Comment: I am a little confused, are you able to connect to you SQL DB? If so I can provide code I use. If not, can you be a little bit more specific on what you can't do based on the code provided.

Comment: You know you sym values in your update don't have numbers right? Was that intentional?

Comment: hmm kinda..what I mean by that is that sym will be the symptoms, I don't have an idea how will I do the sql in the update statement.

Comment: @MonkeyDoug: you can refer to my previous post to better understand what I really need.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859711/vb2008-retrieve-value-from-combobox-selected-item-and-display-to-multiple-textbo#comment20841417_14859711

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to Insert multiple rows in the same query, which is not possible. you need to have separate queries for each row inserted. Loop through the array of textboxes (from you previous question) to insert :

```
Dim arrayOfTextboxes() As TextBox = {symp0, ... put all textboxes here..., symp9}
myConn.Open()

If Duplicate() = False Then

    STRSQL = "insert into diagnose values (@ill, @sym)"

    For i = 0 To arrayOfTextboxes.Count - 1

       If String.IsNullOrEmpty(arrayOfTextboxes(i).Text) Then Continue For

       Using myCmd = New MySqlCommand(STRSQL, myConn)
            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ill", cmbRecord.Text)
            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sym", arrayOfTextboxes(i).Text)              
            myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

    Next          

        MsgBox("Record Added")

Else

      // I don't get what you want to do in the update part yet.

End If

myConn.Close()
```

Comment: You can also refer to my previous post sir to better understand what I'm trying to do.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859711/vb2008-retrieve-value-from-combobox-selected-item-and-display-to-multiple-textbo#comment20841417_14859711

Comment: @VBeginner Ok I will check it out and update my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you for the effort sir. I already tried your code but nothing happened. No errors, when I try to add a record message box "Record Added" appears but when I checked the table, nothing was really added. :(

Comment: ok, I found out that the problem is my `Duplicate()` function and fixed it. I am now able to add a new record in the diagnose table but only 1 row. Say I entered 'cold' as new illness and filled 2 textboxes with symptom1 and symptom 2, only symptom 1 is saved. Also, I'm receiving error: Parameter 'ill' has already been defined.